# How to get the number of specific divs inside another div on Cypress

Tags: cypress

How to filter the subject with id="chatLisHolder" to the elements with only 'userid'

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You will use a `.get()` and use `.find()` to get the divs with userid within #chatListHolder

```js
cy.get('#chatListHolder')
  .find('div[userid]')
```

Alternatively, you can do filter after getting all the child divs:

```js
cy.get('#chatListHolder')
  .children('div')
  .filter('[userid]')
```