# Getting the number of a specific elements inside a div on Cypress

Tags: cypress

How to get the number of divs that contain 'userid' from the div with id="chatListHolder"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzzLh.png

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the number of specific divs inside another div on Cypress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73372914/how-to-get-the-number-of-specific-divs-inside-another-div-on-cypress)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a command that yields an element finds more than one element, it will yield all of them. So, we can then check the yielded array of element's length.

```js
cy.get('#chatListHolder')
  .should('have.length', 1); // we can change that 1 to whatever number we'd like
// or if we need to do something with that
cy.get('#chatListHolder')
  .its('length').should('be.gt', 1);
// or another possibility
cy.get('#chatListHolder')
  .its('length')
  .then((length) => {
  // whatever needs to be done with the length variable
});
```